# TinyMCE instances in jquery sortable

Tags: jquery, tinymce, sortables

I'm stumped and frustrated so time to ask for help.  Done a lot of googling but yet to find a solution that works for me.

What I have is a whole bunch of divs that can be sorted using Jquery sortable, some of divs contain a TinyMCE instance.  Which is all fine until you try to move a div that contains a TinyMCE instance - when you do TinyMCE seems to refresh itself and creates a new instance which you then therefore lose the data etc.  And then the whole page breaks as the javascript no longer works :).  During this time I get javascript constructor errors etc in Firebug.

What I have decided the best way to go is when the div starts to get dragged remove tinymce from the text area and when it is placed in it's new position insert tinymce back in.

I can remove it fine but having trouble adding it back in - as I get more constructor errors.

Note: TinyMCE automatically gets added to all my text areas within the system I'm using so trying to avoid messing with TinyMCE.

In the code below I'm simply targeting a specific textarea id for testing purposes.

```
$cols.sortable({
                            cursor: 'move',
                            revert: true,
                            opacity: 0.6,
                            placeholder: 'widgetplaceholder',
                            forcePlaceholderSize: true,
                            connectWith: cols,
                            zIndex:9000,
                            cancel: ".collapsable_box_editpanel_groups, .collapsable_box_content",
                            start: function(e, ui) {
                                     // removes tinymce ok from textarea
                                     tinyMCE.execCommand( 'mceRemoveControl', false, 'textarea1' );

                            },
                            stop: function(e,ui) {
                                    // breaks here - constructor error
                                    tinyMCE.execCommand( 'mceAddControl', true, 'textarea1' );
                                    $(this).sortable( "refresh" );
                            }
                    });
```

Anybody else have any other solutions?  If you need more information please let me :)

Answer (score 22):

Hey if you already have data in your MCE instances, to avoid losing it, you can try this:

```
start: function(e, ui){
    $(this).find('.tinyMCE').each(function(){
        tinyMCE.execCommand( 'mceRemoveControl', false, $(this).attr('id') );
    });
},
stop: function(e,ui) {
    $(this).find('.tinyMCE').each(function(){
        tinyMCE.execCommand( 'mceAddControl', true, $(this).attr('id') );
        $(this).sortable("refresh");
    });
}
```

In my case i classed all MCE Instances with .tinyMCE

Comment: +1 Helped me a ton! It also helps to understand what it was trying to do is remove the tinyMCE on the textarea and move the naked textarea with the contents in it and once the placements are final it reapplies the tinyMCE again. That should should be helpful not only for jQuery Sortable script but also for any DOM manipulation scripts.

Comment: Works great! Just a note that in TinyMCE 4 the commands have been changed to mceAddEditor and mceRemoveEditor

Comment: This helped me, thank you! But why put the `$(this).sortable("refresh");` in the stop routine? Is there a reason for this? Also I noticed that it is called on each tinymce element, so it seems superfluous...

Comment: Is nobody else bothered by the fact that this causes the textarea to become visible _with its raw HTML content_ while the drag is happening? I mean this works, but it's hella ugly.

Comment: @AlienBishop In Sortable.js it worked by doing both the remove and add in onEnd (after each other), which means that the layout is shown while dragging, then readded after the drop.

Comment: Thanks, it helped me a lot. And I think you should update your answer, taking in regards Honorable Chow answer below which considering dealing with TinyMCE v4

Comment: To those who are bothered about how it looks when you drag, you can actually mceRemoveEditor and then mceAddEditor in the stop function, without doing anything in the start function, and it will flicker for a second but otherwise will look correct when dragging

Answer (score 17):

For version 4 of TinyMCE

```
start: function (e, ui) {
  $(ui.item).find('textarea').each(function () {
     tinymce.execCommand('mceRemoveEditor', false, $(this).attr('id'));
  });
},
stop: function (e, ui) {
  $(ui.item).find('textarea').each(function () {
     tinymce.execCommand('mceAddEditor', true, $(this).attr('id'));
  });
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Well, a stable solution of this problem, for TinyMce v.4+ is :

```
start: function(e, ui){
        tinyMCE.triggerSave();
    },
    stop: function(e,ui) {

        $(this).find('textarea').each(function(){
            tinyMCE.execCommand( 'mceRemoveEditor', false, $(this).attr('id') );

            // if your tinymce instance have different settings
            tinymce.init(tinymce_settings($(this).attr('data-type')));

            tinyMCE.execCommand( 'mceAddEditor', false, $(this).attr('id') );
        });
    }
```

If your textarea have more than one type of settings applied, you must declare `tinymce.init(settings)` before each reset, otherwise the last one applied will apply to all.

An easy way to variate settings is to set a flag of settings type on your textarea such as :

`<textarea data-type="settings_one"></textarea>
 <textarea data-type="settings_two"></textarea>`

and then use a loader function which will distrubute the necessary one :

```
function tinymce_settings(type) {

var settings;

switch(type) {

  case 'settings_one' :
    settings = {...}
    break;
  }    
 return settings;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For anyone trying to dynamically assign "textarea1", the draggable is in the ui object as ui.item. For one textarea per sortable:

```
tinyMCE.execCommand( 'mceAddControl', false,  $('textarea',ui.item)[0].id );

tinyMCE.execCommand( 'mceRemoveControl', false,  $('textarea',ui.item)[0].id );
```

Comment: Your code `$('textarea',ui.item)[0].id` worked well.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up just destroying and recreating the edit on sortable stop() event:

```
stop: function (e, ui) {
  $(this).find('textarea').each(function () {
    tinyMCE.get($(this).attr('id')).destroy();
    // the code below locates and evals the editor init script
    eval($(this).parents('.item').find('script').html());
  });
}
```

Works like a charm and is probably a better option than other suggestions to destroy the editor on start() event and then re-create on stop() - because this way you are still dragging visually appealing editor. P.S. Using TinyMCE 4.5.2

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no other solution. This is the way it needs to be done.
When manipulatin dom elements containing tinymce instances you need to deactivate them and reactivate them when you are done with the dom operation using `mceRemoveControl` and `mceAddControl`.

Answer (score 0):

I have a dynamic form with multiple paragraphs that can all be edited with TinyMCE. To allow re-sorting of the paragraphs, I added buttons that move the textareas up and down.

I managed to get it to work using an alt="textareaid" on the button that moves a textarea up or down, and using this textareaid for the mceRemoveEditor and mceAddEditor commands. The textarea has to be in a div with class="textarea_container".

```
$('.move_textarea_up').click(function(){
    var tinymceid= $(this).attr("alt");
    tinyMCE.execCommand('mceRemoveEditor', false, tinymceid);
    $(this).closest('div.textarea_container').insertBefore($(this).closest('div.textarea_container').prev());
    tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAddEditor', false, tinymceid);
}); 
$('.move_textarea_down').click(function(){
    var tinymceid= $(this).attr("alt");
    tinyMCE.execCommand('mceRemoveEditor', false, tinymceid);
    $(this).closest('div.textarea_container').insertAfter($(this).closest('div.textarea_container').next());
    tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAddEditor', false, tinymceid);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For me worked solution is here. *For version 4 of TinyMCE*

> My Case : I am using sortable jquery with repeater field for meta box
>   inside wordpress. Each sortable element have textarea converted into tinyMCE editor.
>
> **When I was moving one element from sortable items, editor inside only that one element get broken and no content displayed in visual
>   tab.** I used ***mceRemoveEditor*** and ***mceAddEditor*** to prevent problem.

So I came to this final solution after combining some of above solutions. Thanks to @Honorable Chow , @pragmar @Sonicdesign Well your solutions didn't worked for me as they are, so I modified them. Here is my code which is worked fine for me.

```
start: function(e, ui){
        tinyMCE.execCommand( 'mceRemoveEditor', false,  jQuery('textarea',ui.item)[0].id );
    },
    stop: function(e,ui) {
        tinyMCE.execCommand( 'mceAddEditor', false,  jQuery('textarea',ui.item)[0].id );
    }
```

Comment: Any ideas how to make this work with different two different TinyMCE configurations? It seems to only apply the last configuration on sort.

Answer (score 0):

I has able to solve similar problem with:

tinymce.activeEditor.setMode('readonly');

and

tinymce.activeEditor.setMode('design');

this works for version 4.3.x

Answer (score 0):

i have done

```
$("#stores-container").sortable({

        stop: function(event, ui) {

            textareaID = $(ui.item).find(' textarea').attr('id');

            textareaVal=$(ui.item).find(' textarea').val();

            editorID=$(ui.item).find('.mce-container').attr('id');

            $( "#"+editorID ).remove();

            $('#'+textareaID).show();
            tinymce.init({selector: '#'+textareaID});
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
start: function (e, ui) {
  tinyMCE.execCommand( 'mceRemoveEditor', false, editor_id );
},
stop: function (e, ui) {
  tinymce.execCommand('mceAddEditor', true, editor_id);
}
```

This works great just I used for one editor. Thank you very much :) .