# Command identifiers for tinymce 4.x (mceAddControl)

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-4

I am migrating from tinyMCE 3.x to the latest version of tinyMCE 4.x. My problem is that I have dynamic generation of tinyMCE instances so in 3.x I was using:

```
tinymce.EditorManager.execCommand('mceAddControl', true, "content_txt");
```

but in version 4.x this doesn't work. I started to check the documentation but I can't find the identifiers for version 4.x

Answer (score 6):

Migration is very simple, replace

```
tinymce.EditorManager.execCommand('mceAddControl', true, "content_txt");
```

by

```
tinymce.EditorManager.execCommand('mceAddEditor', true, "content_txt");
```

When you want to turn it of, you can use

```
tinymce.EditorManager.execCommand('mceRemoveEditor', false, "content_txt");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `mceRemoveEditor/mceAddEditor` exactly the same commands as stated here http://www.tinymce.com/forum/viewtopic.php?id=31256

Comment: Dead link: Oops... Our Husky got lost.

Answer (score 0):

the add/remove editor execCommands worked but lost the editor's 
configuration. I found these show/hide methods to be more equivalent
to the old add/remove controls commands.

```
tinyMCE.editors[id].show();
tinyMCE.editors[id].hide();
```