# Add TinyMCE editor on sortable divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, tinymce

I am trying to make an application where one can build newsletters in real time by dragging dropping divs and editing them. To sort divs I am using jquery.sortable(), these divs also contain a TinyMCE Editor. Which is working fine until divs are dragged. I have gone through this [link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3919928/tinymce-instances-in-jquery-sortable?rq=1) and [link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5885906/jquery-ui-sortable-on-divs-with-tinymce-editors-causes-text-to-disappear)
but still I am unable to achieve that.

Here is my code

**Markup:**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="sort-List">
        <li>
            <div class="edit-Text">
                <p>Div 1</p>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="edit-Text">
                <p>Div 2</p>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="edit-Text">
                <p>Div 3</p>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="edit-Text">
                <p>Div 4</p>
            </div>
        </li>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
<!--Tiny Mce-->
<script>
    tinymce.init({
        selector: '.edit-Text',
        inline: true,
        menubar: false,
        plugins: "textcolor colorpicker",
        toolbar: ["undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright | forecolor backcolor"],
    });
</script>
<!--Tiny Mce-->    
<!--MAKE DIVS SORTABLE-->
<script>
    $(function () {
        $(".sort-List").sortable({
            cursor: 'move',
            start: function (e, ui) {
                $(this).find('.edit-Text').each(function () {
                    tinyMCE.execCommand('mceRemoveEditor', false, $(this).attr('id'));
                });
            },
            stop: function (e, ui) {
                $(this).find('.edit-Text').each(function () {
                    tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAddEditor', true, $(this).attr('id'));
                });
            },
        });
    });
</script>
<!--MAKE DIVS SORTABLE-->
```

Comment: can you create a js fiddle or tinymce fiddle?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/nsaybgtq/    Here goes the fiddle. Right now it is completely messed up.

Comment: this fidde is of no use without a real tinyme. better try fiddle.tinymce.com

Comment: how about this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34850038/tinymce-4-not-working-with-sortable-jquery-divs