# TinyMCE instances in jquery sortable class all MCE Instances

Tags: tinymce, jquery-ui-sortable

I've encountered a problem when combining JQuery sortable and TinyMCE.

My issue is similar to:
[TinyMCE instances in jquery sortable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3919928/tinymce-instances-in-jquery-sortable); but I don't know how to "*classed all MCE Instances with .tinyMCE*", described in the solution.

It would be grateful if anyone can help me out of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need add "tinyMCE" class for all textareas that used tinyMCE.
If you want use solution from example solution you also need to have unique id for each textarea. Like this

```
<div>
  <textarea class="tinyMCE" id="textarea1"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div>
            <textarea class="tinyMCE" id="textarea2"></textarea>
        </div>
```